# docker with php, nginx, redis, memcached connection refused 111

Tags: php, nginx, docker-compose, redis, yii2

I have a project with Yii2 + nginx + php + redis + other services
What I want
so that each  php, nginx, redis, etc... service located in a separate container

**that does not work**:
access to redis from Yii2 (another container)?

configurations:

file:
**/frontend/config/main.php**

```
return [
    'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
        'redis' => [
            'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 1,
],
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: mnginx
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/nginx.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/ztt.loc
  php-fpm:
    restart: always
    container_name: mphp
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/php-fpm.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/ztt.loc
  redis:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/redis_data/redis.docker
    container_name: mredis
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6379
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.6.17
    container_name: mymemcached
    restart: always
    command: "-p 11211 -m 256 -c 8092"
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
```

**/docker/nginx/nginx.docker**

```
FROM nginx:1.20-alpine
COPY ./docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/conf/ztt.loc.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/ztt.loc.conf
```

**/docker/php/php-fpm.docker**

```
FROM php:7.4.30-fpm
COPY ./docker/php/conf/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
COPY ./docker/php/conf/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./docker/php/conf/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
install-php-extensions zip memcached
```

**/docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf**

```
user       nginx nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    index    index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile     on;
    tcp_nopush   on;
    
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**/docker/nginx/conf/ztt.loc.conf**

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    
    listen 80;
    server_name ztt.loc;
    root /var/www/html/ztt.loc/frontend/web;
    
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ztt.loc.log;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    
    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**/docker/redis_data/redis.docker**

```
FROM redis:6.2.7
COPY ./docker/redis_data/conf/redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

**/docker/redis_data/conf/redis.conf**

```
bind 127.0.0.1
protected-mode no
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 60
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize no
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
loglevel notice
#logfile "/usr/local/var/log/redis.log"
databases 6
always-show-logo no
set-proc-title yes
proc-title-template "{title} {listen-addr} {server-mode}"
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
rdb-del-sync-files no
dir ./
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-diskless-load disabled
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100
acllog-max-len 128
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
lazyfree-lazy-user-del no
lazyfree-lazy-user-flush no
oom-score-adj no
oom-score-adj-values 0 200 800
disable-thp yes
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4096
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
jemalloc-bg-thread yes
```

when i am going to:
**http://ztt.loc/site/index**

page result:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
Failed to open redis DB connection (tcp://127.0.0.1:6379, database=1): 111 - Connection refused
Error Info: Connection refused
```

Its ubuntu 20.04 on local machiene;
I am installed redis-cli;
and i am has access from this redis-client.

Comment: Did you expose the port 6379 on the database container? Can you access it from your browser?

Comment: Yes, I am changed description and added ports to configuration. This don't solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your
**docker-compose.yml**
to

```
version: '3'

networks:
  myztt:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.18.0.1

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: mnginx
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/nginx.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      myztt:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.100
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/ztt.loc
  php-fpm:
    restart: always
    container_name: mphp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/php-fpm.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/ztt.loc
    networks:
      myztt:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.101
  redis:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/redis_data/redis.docker
    container_name: mredis
    restart: always
    networks:
      myztt:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.103
```

and change connection url to 172.18.0.103 in file: **/frontend/config/main.php**

```
'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
            'redis' => [
                'hostname' => '172.18.0.103',
                'port' => 6379,
                'database' => 1,
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: If this worked for you, don't forget to mark the response as correct

Comment: Thank you. I'll do it, when site timeout ended

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you haven't exposed the port in the redis container, it means its not accessible to your machine neither to other containers. You also need to bind it to your local port port so you can access it by pointing to localhost.
You can read further in [docker's docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

```
 redis:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/redis_data/redis.docker
    container_name: mredis
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6379
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

Note the difference in the binding and exposing of port 6379*

Comment: i am added 
expose:
      - 6379
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
      
Its don't solve the problem. I am stoped docker-compose; rebuild, and up again

Comment: There's no expose in the code you put above